# C++: How to check if a directory exists on an FTP server using libcurl

Tags: c++, ftp, libcurl

I'm at my wit's end on this one. I need to check if a directory exists on a remote FTP server. Here's what I'm thinking:

```
//ls - lists the names of the files in the remote directory
string query = "ls /public_html/somefolder/";

//prepare to send
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, query.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, headers); 

//send query to ftp server
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

//check result
if(res == CURLE_OK) {
    cout << "FOLDER EXISTS";
} else {
    cout << "FOLDER DOESN'T EXIST";
}
```

When I check what the `res` variable contains, it outputs:

> CURLE_QUOTE_ERROR (21).

Any ideas on how to do this correctly? I've searched Google profusely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to use `CURLOPT_QUOTE` for this. A `LIST` is a data transfer, so it is handled as part of the `CURLOPT_URL`.

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://ftp@ftp.gnu.org/pub/");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
if(res == CURLE_OK) std::cout << "FOLDER EXISTS\n";
else std::cout << "FOLDER DOESN'T EXIST\n";
```